# How to start gnome 3 not fallback mode in Debian wheezy

Tags: debian, graphics-card, xorg

I installed Debian 7 in the Dell Optplex 9020 Desktop with only one Monitor. But just cannot start gnome 3 instead in fallback mode (like gnome 2.5). I have installed the firmware-linux-nonfree xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-ati. Thank you.

$lspci | grep "VGA" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XTX [Radeon HD 8490 / R5 235X OEM]

$xrandr                                                                                                                                          ──(Thu,Oct02)─┘
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected 1680x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1680x1050       0.0* 
   1280x1024       0.0
   1024x768        0.0
   800x600         0.0
   640x480         0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GPU looks too much new for the Wheezy drivers. I even got myself to recompile mesa-dri in order to make my Intel HD 3000 perfectly work in games, which iGPU was already released in 2011...

Your only hope is to find a newer driver for your R5 235X, or compile a new one.

Comment: When I just unplug it the AMD graphic card, the gnome3 still doesnot work.

Comment: Xeon E3-1200 v3 are from Haswell generation, which is very new compared to Wheezy too, you'll unfortunately have to compile mesa-dri to a newer version, like the 10.2 series.

The problem is, that doing so will force you to compile the other drm modules for radeon and nouveau in order to have more recent ones.

I'm stuck with compiling that too, since in Wheezy mesa-dri can't find any nouveau.h drm header...

Note that mesa-dri 8.0.5 (2012!!!) in Wheezy only use openGL before 3, while mesa-dri 10.2x does. And that your HD P4x00 can use openGL up to 4.0...

Comment: I just installed the Debain Jessie with internet and the gnome3 works on it!